# ng-model within a nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm attempting to build an import for our system. I accept an excel file, parse it within a web api into a data table object (number of columns and rows is unknown). I send the data table via json back to my angular app. After a user maps the columns to fields in our database, I then take the data table, pass it back to an api.

The problem is when I pass the table back to the api, any changes I've made to the data isn't applied. It's as if ng-model isn't working

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in dt track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row">
            <input type='text' ng-model="col" />{{col}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Visually this produces exactly what I want. The {{col}} visually shows me that typing different data shows me ng-model must be updating, because {{col}} always shows the value inside the text box

But when I pass my data table to the api, it contains all the original values

Comment: please share the 'dt' object structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-model="col"` sets the value of `col`, which is a copy of what is in `row[$index]`. To update the value which in `row`, use `ng-model="row[$index]"`.

Comment: Logically what you say here makes sense. With slight tweaking, this solved my problem. Thanks!!